# Laravel blade on VSCode indention problem

Tags: php, laravel

Every time I do a format shortcut (`Alt + Shift + F`) for my `.blade` documents, codes that start with `@` do not indent the way I want them to be. Below is the sample code of an unformatted basic if/else + foreach on a `.blade` file.

```
// unformatted codeblock
<h1 class="poppins-medium text-xl text-darkergreen text-center">
    @if (Auth::user()->role == 'auditor' || Auth::user()->role == 'accreditor')
    @foreach ($documentGalleryTitle as $record)
    @if ((Str::lower(Str::snake(Str::replaceLast(' Taskforce', '', $record->name)))) == $folder_name)
    {{ Str::replaceLast(' Taskforce', '', $record->name) . ' Documents'}}
    @endif
    @endforeach
    @elseif (Auth::user()->role == 'taskforce')
    {{ $userRecord->nonOfficialsCategories->area_number . Auth::user()->subcategory . " Documents" }}
    @endif
</h1>
```

As you can see on the previous codeblock, codes inside the parent `@if/else` should be indented. Same with the codes inside the `@foreach`, and the `@if/endif` codeblock.

I want the codeblock to look like the code below rather than the previous code above:

```
// how it should be
<h1 class="poppins-medium text-xl text-darkergreen text-center">
    @if (Auth::user()->role == 'auditor' || Auth::user()->role == 'accreditor')
        @foreach ($documentGalleryTitle as $record)
            @if ((Str::lower(Str::snake(Str::replaceLast(' Taskforce', '', $record->name)))) == $folder_name)
                {{ Str::replaceLast(' Taskforce', '', $record->name) . ' Documents'}}
            @endif
        @endforeach
    @elseif (Auth::user()->role == 'taskforce')
        {{ $userRecord->nonOfficialsCategories->area_number . Auth::user()->subcategory . " Documents" }}
    @endif
</h1>
```

Is there a particular extension that I need to install + edit to create my desired format?

Comment: Which extension are you using right now? Which ones have you tried already?

Comment: Have you tried searching for "blade format" in the Extensions tab?

Comment: I've installed the 3rd result. the ones created by Shuhei Hayashibara. Seems like it's the extension that I'm looking for.